# Appending to a file using system calls in c

Tags: c, system-calls

Write a program using the five system calls- open(), close(), creat(), read(), write() functions to count the numbers of characters in a file. If the number is even then append two arbitrary characters; otherwise append a single character in that file.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
    char *path="text.txt";
    int fd;
    if((fd = creat(path, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR))<0){     // creat() function used for read purpose only
        write(2,"ERROR!!!",8);
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        char * buff=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
        size_t sz = read(fd, buff, 100);
        close(fd);
        int fd2;         // open() function used for appending purpose
        if((fd2= open(path, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND))<0){
            write(2,"ERROR!!!",8);
            return 0;
        }
        sz-=1;
        if(sz%2==0){
            write(1,"Appending 2 characters",22);
            char *ch="##";  // appending characters
            write(fd2, ch, 2);
        }
        else{
            write(1,"Appending 1 character",21);
            char *ch="#";   // appending character
            write(fd2, ch, 1);
        }
        close(fd2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have used O_APPEND in `fd2= open(path, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND`, yet instead of appending to the file, its writing into after trucating it. Please explain what's wrong with the code.

Comment: The [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/creat.3p.html) tells us: "creat — create a new file or rewrite an existing one". What makes you think, you could use that function to open a file for reading? Did you check the file after `creat´ and before `open`?

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks! Now I understand the problem.